# Apps script and setNumberFormat

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, localization

I have a Google spreadsheet script that pulls some data through API. The problem is that i'm pulling some data that returns a number like this: `142499.68000000`

The problem is that my spreadsheet is configured to brazilian format and i'm getting some crazy results (`14.249.968.000.000,00`). I want to format this number like this: `142.499,68` (we use comma and not dot as US format).

I've been playing around with `.setNumberFormat()` but had no success.

How can I format the number like that in my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript directly and in particular [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat):

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  const number = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(142499.68000000);
  cell.setValue(number);  
}
```

It works for me when I change my spreadsheet locale to Brazil.

Make sure you don't have other number formatting on the cells that could affect the formatting returned by the script.

The `de-DE` version returns the desired result:

[image]