# setNumberFormat with default date format

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I have a Google Apps Script add-on for Google Sheets which receive date timestamp.
I would like to display the timestamp as a date in string format so user could read it.

I have users in US and users in Europe so the date format differ: `mm/dd` or `dd/mm`

Is there a way to use the default locale format with `setNumberFormat` ?

Comment: The javascript date object has a method named toLocaleString

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483840/apps-script-and-setnumberformat

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887732/get-time-format-according-to-spreadsheet-locale